# how to Recognize signed/encrypted mails in outlooks

Tags: encryption, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments, smime

Generally in outlook messages can be encrypted with either S/MIME encryption or Microsoft 365 Message Encryption (IRM).

In order to identify and filter messages encrypted in either of the above two methods analyzed the internet message headers and Microsoft graph API values of those encrypted message samples found no clue to consider a message be a encrypted/signed. but, found something in common from the graph API response that each of these messages contains an attachment that is not attached by the sender in the email body.

common cases found in mails encrypted/signed in different ways based on analyzing sample mails:
**MIME signed messages** contains an attachment with

```
   name: "smime.p7m" & content type: "multipart/signed"
```

**MIME encrypted messages** contains an attachment with

```
   name: "smime.p7m" & content type: "application/pkcs7-mime"
```

**IRM encrypted messages** contains an attachment with

```
   name: "message.rpmsg" or "message_v2.rpmsg" & content type: "application/x-microsoft-rpmsg-message"
```

However I feel this is insufficient for me to recognize a encrypted/signed mail as it is completely based on assumption with common cases found in some sample encrypted/signed mails and with this ten year old stack question [check-if-a-outlook-mail-msg-is-digitaly-signed-or-encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136697/check-if-a-outlook-mail-msg-is-digitaly-signed-or-encrypted) describing the similar case with additional set of assumptions.
It would be helpful if one of you could guide me by suggesting any other valid approach to handle this or anything that I missed to try out or to proceed with the collected details.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to request `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` MAPI property (`0x001A001F`). It will be `"IPM.Note.SMIME.MultipartSigned"` for the signed messages or `"IPM.NOTE.SMIME"` for the encrypted messages (or just check if it ends in `".SMIME"`)

Use `"expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x001A')"` when retrieving the message in Graph.

Comment: hi @Dmitry Streblechenko, thanks for the info It'll be useful for me to identify the MIME encrypted mails. do you have any idea on recognizing IRM mails encrypted!

Comment: Yes, same thing. I don't remember the value off the top of my head - you can look it up in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm - I am its author) - click IMessage button, locate the PR_MESSAGE_CLASS property. If it is still "IPM.Note" (Outlook wraps signed/encrypted messages into a fake message), click IMAPISecureMessage|GetBaseMessage to see the raw message and its message class. If you want to see Graph data, click Message button in the Graph group. You can request additional MAPI properties by clicking QueryParameters|$expand and then a button next to the edit box to select.